# Alternative to xctool for running tests on Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

It looks like xctool is [being deprecated and is not going to support Xcode 8](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/704).

I'm wondering what tool I can use to easily build and run my test suite for iOS in a continuous integration server.

Comment: Have you found a solution since you've posted your question? I am at the same crossroads so any info on what you've tried, what worked / didn't would be helpful.

Comment: Didn't find a solution. I'm currently using xcrun, which is not a real alternative for everything but did the job for me.